# Use purrr's map to estimate linear regressions by group when some groups are empty for some models

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to estimate many linear regressions for many groups.
I use the tidyverse, so I tried `purrr`'s `map` and `broom`'s `tidy`.

However, not all groups have observations for all variables in all models.
In my example below, `z` is missing when `t` is 1, so `lm` cannot estimate `y ~ x + z` when `t` is 1.
I thought a `filter` statement in each `lm` would solve the problem.
However, sometimes `filter` provides an empty data set, and `lm` throws an error.

I thought that `map` would have an option to handle these cases, but I do not see one in the help file.

Is there a best practice here? FWIW, I only want the coefficient estimates. If you swap the commented `mutate` the code works as expected.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(t = rep(1:2, each = 10),
             y = runif(20),
             x = runif(20)) %>%
    mutate(z = ifelse(t == 1, NA, runif(20)))
    # mutate(z = runif(20))


results <- df %>%
    nest(dat = -t) %>%
    mutate(
        model_1 = map(dat, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .x %>% drop_na(y, x))),
        model_2 = map(dat, ~ lm(y ~ x + z, data = .x %>% drop_na(x, z))),
        coef_1 = map(model_1, tidy),
        coef_2 = map(model_2, tidy)
    ) %>%
    select(t, starts_with('coef')) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with('coef')
    ) %>% 
    unnest(value)
#> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...): 0 (non-NA) cases
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I've sometimes used `purrr::possibly()` or `purrr::safely()` when I want to set what a function should return when an error occurs.  For example, maybe you'd use it for `lm()` or `tidy()` in this case.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks! `purrr::possibly()` is the "option" that I want. It makes sense for this "option" to be a standalone function; I was looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `unnest`, the default is `keep_empty = FALSE`, but here the issue is at the model creation as all the values in 'z' are NA.  We can create a condition with `if/else`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     nest(dat = -t) %>%
     mutate(
         model_1 = map(dat, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .x %>% drop_na(y, x))),
         model_2 = map(dat, ~ if(all(is.na(.x$z))) NULL else 
               lm(y ~ x + z, data = .x %>% drop_na(x, z))),
         coef_1 = map(model_1, tidy),
         coef_2 = map(model_2, tidy)) %>% 
      select(t, starts_with('coef')) %>% 
      pivot_longer(
         cols = starts_with('coef')
     ) %>% 
     unnest(c(value))
# A tibble: 7 x 7
#      t name   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#  <int> <chr>  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 coef_1 (Intercept)    0.333     0.196     1.70  0.127  
#2     1 coef_1 x              0.444     0.386     1.15  0.283  
#3     2 coef_1 (Intercept)    0.852     0.195     4.37  0.00239
#4     2 coef_1 x             -0.854     0.363    -2.35  0.0463 
#5     2 coef_2 (Intercept)    0.597     0.438     1.36  0.215  
#6     2 coef_2 x             -0.659     0.479    -1.37  0.212  
#7     2 coef_2 z              0.280     0.425     0.658 0.532
```

Comment: Thanks. Your logic is what I needed. In practice, I will use @aosmith 's comment and generate the `NULL` with `purrr::possibly`: `possibly_lm <- possibly(lm, NULL)`